# Is there a free website to store code (php, javascript, css) online?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am looking for website to store my code and then reused if may I need it. Would be great something like Delicious but for coding or something like Snippely.

Comment: For "server-side" languages: [Wikipedia: Comparison of open source software hosting facilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_software_hosting_facilities)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can host your code on solutions like [Google code](http://code.google.com), [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) or [GitHub](http://github.com).

If your code is more a snippet you can choose solutions like [snipplr](http://snipplr.com/) or [Gist](http://gist.github.com/gists)

Comment: None of these links point to the right pages anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Google code (code.google.com) does that for Project coordination.
JSfiddle (jsfiddle.net) is pretty awesome when you have HTML, JS and CSS.

Answer (score 2):

[Github](https://github.com/) with its [gists](http://gist.github.com/)

Answer (score 0):

thousands of websites out there. http://snipplr.com/ for example. just bought by envato and it will get some really neat new features. also works together with some apps like textmate or something

Answer (score 0):

For code snippets how about http://gist.github.com ?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to go the route of project coordination and hosting, there is also GitHub.